# Utilizing a single view to load multiple viewmodels with Prism 7 and WPF

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a shell application that has in it a single window and single control the window has a tabcontrol as a region.  The usercontrol has 2 content controls as regions "List" / "Details".  I was hoping to be able to let the SplitWindow User control load the module containing the list view and detail view of whichever viewmodels I needed.  I am sorry if this is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the design.  Not as happy as I would like but moved the split window user control to each individual module.  Then in the shell I call request navigate on a scoped region.